# Negative version of I can see forever

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

PHD turns all bad pills in good pills.

I had two "I Can See Forever" pills in a run with PHD.

What is the negative pill that turns into "I Can See Forever"?

Comment: At a guess, Amnesia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No pill is converted to *I Can See Forever* by the PhD or similar effects.

It is, however, possible for the same pill to appear twice in the same game. In this case, your game would have had two different pills with *I Can See Forever*.

Source:
http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/PHD
http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Pills

Comment: Strange the wiki says amnesia is converted to telepils that's why i asked the question i thought amnesia in the first place

Answer (score 1):

PHD turns all bad pills in good pills, but there are **neutral** pills too, so effects like *Puberty*, *I can see forever*, *Bad gas*, *48 Hour Energy*, *Bombs are key* and *Pheromones* won't be converted.
You can still find them after collecting PhD.